# Two questions about mvvm navigation of pages

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, combobox, navigation

I am trying to make a template-translator (.doc) from EN to other languages.

It is just for me.

I have already done simple mvvm navigation. For clear understanding what do I want, check picture:

[image: UI]

**First question:** How do I translate ICommand from button "NextItem" to current selected page that has changed a item inside textBox, otherwise how do I Call Translate() method from current page for my Button which is in the MainView?

**Second question:** How do I put all pages that I have on the Window in the Combobox on the Upper side window, and select page from there, like I do this with my Buttons.

How it is now:

```
<Button
    x:Name="ButtonSecondView"
    Width="200"
    Command="{Binding GoToSecondViewCommand}"
    Content="SecondView" />

<Button
    x:Name="ButtonNextItem"
    Grid.Row="2"
    Width="250"
    Command="{Binding NextRandomItem}"
    Content="Next item" />
```

MyCollection is just a stub which generates random items(1 item, 3 item, etc...).
There I can translate some parameters to page while it is initializing.

```
public MainViewModel()
{
    MyCollection = new MyCollection();
    CurrentViewModel = new FirstViewModel(this,MyCollection.GetRandomItem());
    PageList = MyCollection.GetList();
}

public ICommand GoToFirstViewCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() => { CurrentViewModel = new FirstViewModel(this, MyCollection.GetRandomItem()); });
        }
    }

public ICommand GoToSecondViewCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return new RelayCommand(() => { CurrentViewModel = new SecondViewModel(this, MyCollection.GetRandomItem()); });
        }
    }
```

ctor in SecondViewModel

```
public SecondViewModel(INotifyContentChanged contentChanged,string Parametrs)
{
    ContentChanged = contentChanged;
    TextContent = Parametrs;
}
```

**One more time: First question.**

I have many pages (in there 3), and I need to click the button on bottom, and in my page. In my current page I get text from textBox, and input these parameters to my method, like Translate(string field1). And this works on all pages that I want. If I change page in which I select Combobox items, I can do the same button click to button, and text from textBox inputted in my method Translate(string field1).

Comment: Rather doing like this Bind single command in main ViewModel and pass the index from the button in mina view based on index return the required VM.

Comment: Please, could you try to rephrase your first question? I will address it in my answer then. Right now I don't understand the meaning.

Comment: Thank you. I updated my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To navigate and pass the parameters to the corresponding page view models I stick to your pattern and used composition. I introduced a composition container that holds all page view models in a `Dictionary<string, IPageViewModel>`. Therefore all page view models must implement this interface. As the key I used the page view model's type name (e.g. `nameof(FirstViewModel)`). I also introduced a new property called `PageNavigationParameter` that binds to the `TextBox` in order to get the content (which is supposed to be passed to the corresponding page view model).

A second `Dictionary<string, string>` maps the display name of each page view model (the page name to be displayed in the `ComboBox`) to the actual page view model name (that matches the class name e.g. `nameof(FistViewModel)`). This way you can get the desired page view model by class name or if in the navigation scope from the page display name.

To select pages from a `ComboBox` you could do this:

1. create a collection of page names in the view model and bind it to the `ComboBox.ItemSource`
2. bind the `ComboBox.SelectedItem` property to the view model
3. navigate to page when the view model's property changed

---

To make this example work you need a common interface that all page view models must implement (e.g. `class FirstViewModel : IPageViewModel`). This interface must contain at least the `PageNavigationParameter`

**The page view model interface**

```
interface IPageViewModel
{
  string PageNavigationParameter { get; set; }
}
```

**Main view model (using composition)**

```
class MainViewModel
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
      // The Dictionary to get the page view model name 
      // that maps to a page display name
      this.PageViewModelNameMap = new Dictionary<string, string>()
      {
         {"First Page", nameof(FirstViewModel)},
         {"Second Page", nameof(SecondViewModel)}
      };

      // The ComboBox's items source
      // that holds the page view model display names
      this.PageNames = new ObservableCollection<string>(this.PageViewModelNameMap.Keys);

      // The Dictionary that stores all page view models 
      // that can be retrieved by the page view model type name
      this.PageViewModels = new Dictionary<string, IPageViewModel>()
      {
         {nameof(FirstViewModel), new FirstViewModel()},
         {nameof(SecondViewModel), new SecondViewModel()}
      };

      this.CurrentPageViewModel = this.PageViewModels[nameof(FirstViewModel)];
      this.PageNavigationParameter = string.Empty;
    }

    // You can use this method as execute handler 
    // for your NavigateToPage command too
    private void NavigateToPage(object parameter)
    {
      if (!(parameter is string pageName))
      {
        return;
      }

      if (this.PageViewModelNameMap.TryGetValue(pageName, out string pageViewModelName)
      {
        if (this.PageViewModels.TryGetValue(pageViewModelName, out IPageViewModel pageViewModel)
        {
          pageViewModel.PageNavigationParameter = this.PageNavigationParameter;
          this CurrentPageViewModel = pageViewModel;
        }
      }
    }

    private bool CanExecuteNavigation(object parameter) => parameter is string destinationPageName && this.PageViewModelNameMap.Contains(destinationPageName);

    private void OnSelectedPageChanged(string selectedPageName)
    {
      NavigateToPage(selectedPageName);
    }

    private ObservableCollection<string> pageNames;   
    public ObservableCollection<string> PageNames
    {
      get => this.pageNames;
      set 
      { 
        this.pageNames = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    private string selectedPageName;   
    public string SelectedPageName
    {
      get => this.selectedPageName;
      set 
      { 
        this.selectedPageName = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
        OnSelectedPageChanged(value);
       }
     }

    private string pageNavigationParameter;   
    public string PageNavigationParameter

    {
      get => this.pageNavigationParameter;
      set 
      { 
        this.pageNavigationParameter= value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, ViewModelBase> pageViewModels;   
    public Dictionary<string, ViewModelBase> PageViewModels
    {
      get => this.pageViewModels;
      set 
      { 
        this.pageViewModels = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    private Dictionary<string, string> pageViewModelNameMap;   
    public Dictionary<string, string> PageViewModelNameMap
    {
      get => this.pageViewModelNameMap;
      set 
      { 
        this.pageViewModelNameMap = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
      }
    }

    private IPageViewModel currentPageViewModel;   
    public IPageViewModel CurrentPageViewModel 
    {
      get => this.currentPageViewModel;
      set 
      { 
        this.currentPageViewModel= value; 
        OnPropertyChanged();
       }
     }
  }
```

The controls that have a cross page scope must have the `MainViewModel`  as their `DataContext`.

**XAML snippet**

```
<!-- The page menu (DataContext is MainViewModel) -->
<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPageName}" ItemsSource="{Binding PageNames}" />

<!-- The navigation parameter TextBox (DataContext is MainViewModel) -->
<TextBox Text="{Binding PageNavigationParameter}" />
```

For your navigation button commands you can use the same `MainViewModel.NavigateToPage()` method as the execute delegate handler and `CanExecuteNavigation` as the can execute handler. So you now have a single navigation command (e.g. `NavigateToPage`) that navigates to the destination page by passing the page display name as `CommandParameter`.